# Heroku deployment is not workig says Expected another key-value pair

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, heroku

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "creative-agency-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Meherameem",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

After deploying to Heroku it says

***-----> Node.js app detected
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 21, column 3
!     Unable to parse package.json
-----> Build failed***

Comment: I dont see any problem in json, might be issues with parser

Comment: can you direct me please where should I look to solve this problem?
I have the main files in git. index.js, package.json and  package-lock.json. The code runs smoothly in the local environment .

Comment: Just check in your production json if any ',' in the end of last node.. this is the reason why one get this kind of parsing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was -

```
"dotenv": "^8.2.0"
```

should be inside the ***dependencies*** while deploying on Heroku. Weird that the error on the Heroku console was a bit ambiguous.